# Trying to get property of non-object foreach laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, foreach, laravel-5

edit function

```
public function edit($id)
{
   $spesifikasi = logistik_spesifikasi::find($id);
   return view('logistik.edit_spesifikasi', get_defined_vars());
}
```

logistik_spesifikasi model

```
class logistik_spesifikasi extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'logistik_spesifikasi';
    protected $primarykey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = ['nama_produk', 'satuan', 'tipe', 'jumlah', 'id_satuan','id_produk'];

    public function listMaterial()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ListMaterial', 'id_produk');
    }


    public function satuanList()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\LogistikSatuan', 'id_satuan');
    }

}
```

ListMaterial Model:

```
class ListMaterial extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'list_material';

    protected $primarykey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = ['id_material', 'id_produk', 'volume'];

    public function material()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\material', 'id_material');
    }

}
```

edit_spesifikasi.blade.php

```
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Nama Material</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach($spesifikasi as $row )
    <tr class="gradeU">
     <td>{{ $row->listMaterial->first()->material->first()->nama_material }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

gettting error

> Trying to get property of non-object (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\hutama-prima\resources\views\logistik\edit_spesifikasi.blade.php)

Comment: Where is the code where you are passing $spesifikasi variable to view?

Comment: this 
public function edit($id)
{
   $spesifikasi = logistik_spesifikasi::find($id);
   return view('logistik.edit_spesifikasi', get_defined_vars());
}


sorry, my english is not good. i'm indonesian :)

Comment: I believe its' view('logistik.edit_spesifikasi', get_defined_vars()); 
I'm not sure why you are using get_defined_vars()?

Comment: like this ??


public function edit($id)
    {
        $spesifikasi = logistik_spesifikasi::find($id);
        return view('logistik.edit_spesifikasi', compact('spesifikasi'));
    }

Comment: You can send like this :return view('logistik.edit_spesifikasi', ['spesifikasi'=>$spesifikasi]);

Comment: the error is the same

Comment: if not using looping then it works, but if using looping does not work

Comment: I guess then you don't need to use foreach loop afterall

Comment: logistik_spesifikasi::find($id); is returning single model instance only so is there need of foreach?

Comment: What is nama_material , material , listMaterial anyway?

Comment: donee broo... thanks very muchh

Answer (score 0):

First check

```
$spesifikasi = logistik_spesifikasi::find($id);
```

$spesifikasi does not empty. If $spesifikasi is empty then you get this error.

Then,

```
public function edit($id)
{
   $spesifikasi = logistik_spesifikasi::find($id);
   if($spesifikasi)
   {
       return view('logistik.edit_spesifikasi', compact('spesifikasi'));
   }
  else
   { 
      //empty....
   }

}
```

Use this code.

```
    @foreach($spesifikasi->listMaterial as $row )
      <tr class="gradeU">
      <td>{{ $row->nama_material }}</td>
      </tr>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: the error is the same.


getting error 

**Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\hutama-prima\resources\views\logistik\edit_spesifikasi.blade.php)**

Comment: Do you check it??

Comment: so, I use the relationships of the tables broo

Comment: Remove foreach. and now check my answer

Comment: It should not be work... I think i got it. Give few minutes.

Comment: @foreach($spesifikasi->listMaterial as $row )
        <tr class="gradeU">
         <td>{{ $row->material->first()->nama_material }}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach

this works bro, thank you very much broo

Comment: If it works. You should accept my answer. For printing purpose i just use demo.